# RSS feed not showing up

Tags: xml, rss

I feel like I have messed up kinda bad somewhere. I have created an RSS feed I tested it out and everything looked awesome but it wasnt validating. Went to my domain.com/rss.xml and all of my RSS items were exactly where I had placed them. I then added in `xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`, closed it off with `/atom:link` and validated it and everything validated perfect this time problem is now when I go to the feed, the actual items in the feed do not show up as they did before and the feed itself is missing items.

Anyone know where I have went wrong here? This is pretty much my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<title>Site Title</title>
<description>Site/RSS Description</description>
<link>http://www.domain.com</link>
<atom:link href="http://www.domain.com/rss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml">

<item>
<category>Website</category>
<title>Item Title</title>
<description>Item Description</description>
<link>http://www.domain.com</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 30 Jun 2014 12:00:00 MDT</pubDate>
</item>

</atom:link>
</channel>

</rss>
```

Comment: Share the URL of the feed please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<atom:link>` (and its closing counterpart) is clearly not right...